# Error when trying to delete a folder. Input is not valid Modified UTF-8

Tags: android, file-io, directory, delete-file, delete-directory

I have a folder with some files, one of those called 'dise�o.jpg'. When I try to remove the folder with the following sentence:

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(pathUnidadRenamed);
```

the app crashes throwing the following error:

```
  JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: 
  input is not valid Modified UTF-8: llegal start byte 0xa4
  string: 'dise�o.jpg'in call to NewStringUTF
  from java.lang.String[] java.io.File.listImpl(java.lang.String)
```

I already know that if I sign the app, it will not crash (but it will not remove the folder), but in this case I need to remove the folder and I do not have the possibility to rename the file due to customer requirements.

Does anyone know how to avoid that error? Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your filename shows as "dise?o.jpg" on my computer. What is the unicode code of the special character between the "e" and the "o" ? Did you write it as-is in code ? You should probably use the "\u1234" notation in your Java files and your SO question, this would be easier to understand/solve.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved my problem with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec( rm -r + " " + path );`